# How to access the value from select2 in django

Tags: ajax, django, django-views, jquery-select2

I'm a beginner in this.I have a select2 plugin with multiple inputs.I want to get all the option values when submitted as an array (to query in views.py).
for eg: [2,134,4,65]

template

```
<div class="col-sm-9">
    <h1>Hello {{user.first_name}} {{user.last_name}}....</h1>
    <h4>Please Specify Your Symptoms</h4>
    <select class="js-example-basic-multiple" name="states[]" multiple="multiple" style="width:300px">
    {% for sym in all_symptoms %}
    <option value={{sym.syd}}>{{sym.symptoms}}</option>
    {% endfor %}
    </select>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
  </div>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
$('.js-example-basic-multiple').select2();
});
  </script>
```

views.py

Answer (score 3, accepted):

change this line

```
<select class="js-example-basic-multiple" name="states[]" multiple="multiple" style="width:300px">
```

to

```
<select class="js-example-basic-multiple" name="states" multiple="multiple" style="width:300px">
```

and in django view

```
request.POST.getlist('states')
```

Comment: before entering the last sentence I have to add the method= post in template.right?

Comment: You are using ajax right? You need post method. And if you do everything correct then you will the list. And also removed the extra bracket what was there in the answer

Comment: In the Django view it needs to be **request.POST.getlist('states[]')**